# Проблема с получением продолжительности аудио

Tags: javascript, аудио, mp3

```
<audio class="myAudio" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Используя этот код получаю что duration моего объекта равен infinity, с чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: Предположу, что потоковая передача без `content-length`.

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что по умолчанию node.js не работает со статичными файлами так, как нам хотелось бы. Для этой цели лучше установить модуль Express при помощи простой команды `npm install express --save`.

Далее необходимо создать файл server.js со следующим содержимым:

```
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 10001;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

После этого создайте папку public и переместите в нее все файлы проекта (.html, .css, .js, изображения и т.п.).

Наконец, запустите свой сервер с помощью модуля Express при помощи коротенькой команды `node server.js`

Подробнее читайте [здесь](http://ericsowell.com/blog/2014/6/17/enough-node-for-building-a-simple-website).